# comparing the elements in an array

Tags: objective-c

```
myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];
[m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
if (pEvent->uExpirationTime < m_cPendingEventList->uExpirationTime) {

        }
[m_cPendingEventList addObject:myData];
```

pEvent is a structure here.I'm trying to compare the expiration time with the expiration time field of the structure stored in the NSMutableArray m_cPendingEventList.
How to do that.The above if condition fails and is showing error.

Error:'struct NSMutableArray' has no member named 'uExpirationTime'

pEvent is a pointer to the structure containing uExpirationTime,uPeriod,etc as fields.

Comment: what kind of structure is pEvent? and what is the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast your `pEvent` to `stRs232Timer`, provided that everything else is correct with your code (I am guessing this from this: `length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)`)

```
myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];
[m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
if ((stRs232Timer*)pEvent->uExpirationTime < m_cPendingEventList->uExpirationTime) {
```

in last line I added the cast...

if this does not work, can you provide the declaration of `pEvent`?

Comment: error: 'struct NSMutableArray' has no member named 'uExpirationTime'
Is the error i'm getting event after doing the same thing what you told me to do.

Comment: I tried my code with this but its still with error.if ((stRs232Timer*)pEvent->uExpirationTime < [m_cPendingEventList objectAtIndex:i]->uExpirationTime)

Comment: @Alvin: either you provide pEvent declaration and possibly the code the comes before the snippet you showed us, or it will be impossible to help...

Comment: The code got fixed.Actually i missed to intialise a pointer to struct with the object returning from the NSArray.Thanks.

Comment: I could able to guess where i'm doing wrong from your post.Thanks.